# color line of scatter plot on all subplot depending on a column

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

python==3.8, plotly==4.14.3

MRE:

```
start_date = "20210716"
end_date = "20210730"

date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date).strftime("%Y%m%d")
A = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=len(date_range)*2)
B = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=len(date_range)*2)
names = ["albert", "chris"]
C = names*(len(date_range))

df = pd.DataFrame({"date":list(date_range)*2,
                   "A":A,
                   "B":B,
                   "C":C})

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%Y%m%d")
df.set_index(["date"], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

which looks like this:

```
            A   B   C
date         
2021-07-16  48  62  Albert
2021-07-16  23  44  Chris
2021-07-17  7   21  Albert
2021-07-17  5   99  Chris
2021-07-18  9   28  Albert
     ...
```

I want to create a subplot with the following

1. scatter plot with columnA as y-axis
2. scatter plot with columnB as y-axis
3. each line in scatter plot are colored using columnC

most answers to similar questions uses clustered.iplot or plotly express. I want to stick to `plotly.graph_objects`.

This is my take:

```
colors = ["blue", "yellow"]

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

for i, col in enumerate(["A", "B"]):
    for name, color in zip(names, colors):
        n_df = df.loc[df["C"] == name].copy()
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                name = f"{i}_{name}",
                x = n_df.index,
                y = n_df[col],
                marker_color = color
                
            ),
            row=i+1, col=1
        )
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text=col, row=i+1, col=1)
fig.show()
```

This does the job however as more names come in I do not want to add new color everytime.
Is there any more easily maintainable way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the built-in color scale. However, since it has 10 colors, it can support up to 10 people. If you need more than that, you can prepare colors for, say, 20 people, instead of the current two. Since this is a loop process, only the number of people needed from the beginning will be used. See continuous and divergent color scales in the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/builtin-colorscales/#builtin-sequential-color-scales).

```
import plotly.express as px
# colors = ["blue", "yellow"]
colors = px.colors.sequential.Plasma
# ['#0d0887','#46039f','#7201a8','#9c179e','#bd3786','#d8576b','#ed7953','#fb9f3a','#fdca26','#f0f921']
```

Since the order of the colors is continuous, we need to shuffle them using `random.sample()`.

```
import random
colors = random.sample(colors, len(colors))
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect however do not want to use `plotly.express`. All my code uses `plotly.graph_object` and want to keep it consistent if possible.

Comment: @haneulkim, plotly is only used to generate the colors.